# В чем разница между CCow::Function() и Function()?

Tags: c++

Можно ли так писать код? И если да, то в чем разница между вот этим: "DisplayCowInfo()" и этим: "CCow::DisplayCowInfo()"

**Cow.h**

---

```
#pragma once

#include <string>

class CCow
{
  public:
    void ObtainCowInfo();
    void DisplayCowInfo();

  private:
    string mName;
    int mAge;
    int mWeight;
}
```

---

**Cow.cpp**

---

```
#include "Cow.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void DisplayCowInfo()
{
  
}

void CCow::ObtainCowInfo()
{
  cout << "Type Cow Information" << endl;
  cout << "--------------------" << endl;
  
  cout << "Cow's name: ";
  cin >> mName;
  cout << endl;

  // Inputting the cow's age, until valid input is inputted
  cout << "Cow's age: ";
  while(true)
  {
    cin >> mAge;
    if(mAge){
      break;
    }
    cout << "Invalid age, try again!" << endl;
  }
  cout << endl;

  // Inputting the cow's weight, until valid input is inputted
  cout << "Cow's weight: ";
  while(true)
  {
    cin >> mWeight;
    if(mWeight){
      break;
    }
    cout << "Invalid weight, try again!" << endl;
  }
  cout << endl;
}
```

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если Вы видите в коде "DisplayCowInfo()" и "CCow::DisplayCowInfo()", то это может быть как одна и та же функция, так и разные. Добавив в начало `CCow::`, Вы уточняете какую именно функцию Вы хотите использовать (в данном случае функцию-член класса CCow).

Когда компилятор видит просто DisplayCowInfo() - у него могут быть "варианты" - это может быть как вызов обычной функции, так функции-члена класса. Все сильно зависит от "места вызова".

Теперь посмотрим на Ваш код. У Вас в объявлении класса CCow есть только объявление функции DisplayCowInfo. Значит где то в другом месте должна быть ее реализация. И она должна иметь вид

```
void CCow::DisplayCowInfo()
{
  
}
```

У Вас же есть просто

```
void DisplayCowInfo()
{
  
}
```

то есть, обычная функция.

А теперь, что же будет происходить.

Если Вы попробуете позвать функцию CCow::DisplayCowInfo() (в коде это может выглядеть как `CCow::DisplayCowInfo()`, `DisplayCowInfo()` или даже `this->DisplayCowInfo()`), будет ругаться линковщик, так как он не найдет ее реализации. Пока Вы ее не вызываете, линковщику нет дела до нее и все даже скомпилируется.

Если Вы вызовите `DisplayCowInfo()` вне класса CCow, то все тоже будет работать - такая функция есть.

Если вызвать вот так `::DisplayCowInfo()`, то будет вызвана "обычная функция" и тоже все будет работать.

Чем функция-член класса отличается от обычной функции? В первом случае есть неявный параметр this, в котором передается указатель на текущий объект.

Comment: спасибо за объяснение)

Comment: KoVadim, в очередной раз аплодирую Вашей способности объяснять понятно!

Comment: я пытался, мне кажется можно сделать чуть лучше. Но я рад, что кому то помогает